# Batch: Exclude certain files from select list

Tags: list, batch-file, select

I have several txt-files containing the same set of variables with different parameters. I created a batch to read in all txt-files from a folder and create a select list. This works fine so far.

Now I want to exclude certain txt-files from the select list, since these don't contain variables (i.e. readme.txt, information.txt).

This is the code I have got so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

:: Read in files
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)

echo.
echo Select one:
echo.

:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
   )
echo.

:: Retrieve User input
set /p select=? 
echo.

:: Print out selected filename
echo You chose !choice[%select%]!

for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!choice[%select%]!") do endlocal & set "VAR=%%~A"

:: Read variables from configuration file.

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%VAR%) do set %%G=%%H
```

Can someone help me to exclude the above mentioned files readme.txt etc which are located in the folder with the parameter files (ie. param1.txt, param2.txt) as well?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use an `If` statement, e.g. `If /I Not "%%~nx"=="information" If /I Not "%%~nx"=="readme" (Set /A...` or use a `FindStr` statement, e.g. `For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%x in ('Dir/B/A-D-L *.txt 2^>Nul^|FindStr/BIV "information\. readme\."')Do (`

Comment: @compo shouldn't it be `/ive` and include the extension?

Comment: I could have done that @LotPings, but, I was providing ideas, not an answer. Even that wouldn't have been robust enough, because as you know, `Dir *.txt` doesn't just pick up `.txt` files, so your code would count and include `readme.txtz`, not to mention it ignoring `pleasereadme.txt` and `more information.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @Compo for your input. I went for the code LotPings provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse output of a dir cmd filtered by a findstr to exclude filenames

```
:: Read in files
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('
    Dir /B /A-D *.txt ^|findstr /ive "readme\.txt information\.txt"
') do (
  set /a count+=1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
```

Comment: Thanks @LotPings. This code works perfectly and only adds a bit more of text.